# Solr 4.1 Solr Cloud Shard Structure

Tags: solr, lucene, sharding

If I plan on holding 7TB of data in a Solr Cloud, is it bad practice to begin with 1 server holding 100 shards and then begin populating the collection where once the size grew, each shard ultimately will be peeled off into its own dedicated server (holding ~70GB ea with its own dedicated resources and replicas)?

That is, I would start the collection with 100 shards locally, then as data grew, I could peel off one shard at a time and give it its own server -- dedicated w/plenty of resources.

Is this okay to do -- or would I somehow incur a massive bottleneck internally by putting that many shards in 1 server to start with while data was low?

Answer (score 0):

This seems valid strategy for Solr 4.1 as Mark Miller one of the main contributor to the project also mentioned this approach check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=eVK0wLkLw9w#t=1692)

However if you can upgrade or planning to upgrade. It is possible to add new shrad dynamically in Solr after 4.3
check [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud)